# Could not instantiate the Payment module

Tags: java, web, paypal, konakart

I added a new language in KonaKart app and I've added all necessary property files.
I activated the modules: `shipping` and `payment`.

For standard languages the modules work fine, but for my added languages I get the following exception:

> Can't find bundle for base name com.konakart.bl.modules.payment.paypal.Paypal lacale ru
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException

in the folder `/com/konakart/bl/modules/payment/paypal` I've added the file `Paypal_ru.properties`
I think I need to add a property file to the classpath.

**How do I add the property file to the classpath?**

Answer (score 0):

With KonaKart you get the full source code for the modules and an ANT build file to rebuild the jars.  Hence the easiest way to do this is to add the properties file for your new locale in the appropriate directory for your module and rebuild the jar.